# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)}{n^2} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am trying to get this to equal $\displaystyle-\frac {\pi^a}{b}$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$ . My efforts so far give:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)}{n^2} \,dx=A-B+C$

where   $A=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\zeta(3)}{n^3}=2\zeta(3)^2$

and  $C=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2}{3n^4}=\frac{\pi^6}{270}$

and  $B=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^6}$ with f(1)=6, f(2)=34, f(3)=393/4, f(4)=5750/27, f(5)=339059/864, f(6)=325493/500, f(7)=36107863/36000, ... ,f(11)=29071954407257/8001504000, ...

I can not figure out what $f(n)$ might be. The sequences of numerators and denominators are unrecognized by  OEIS. Maybe I am off the track.

Perhaps a different approach from the beginning would be better. The results for  A and C were interesting anyway.

Comment: This will sound very naive, but what exactly makes you think there is a nice closed form to begin with?

Comment: I was led to believe there is a closed form like $-\frac{\pi^a}{b}$

Comment: Oh... in that case, can you include how you got to this $A-B+C$ expression? (this could help to answer, although this may be a long shot.)

Comment: I did a quick calculation with GNU Maxima for solving the integrals, the terms A,B,C come from the value of the integral being a triple sum, where one summand contains $\zeta(3)$, one $\pi^2$ and the last is a rational number. The ones with $\zeta(3)$ and with $\pi^2$ can be found with rational interpolation for arbitrary $n$. I don't have a recipe for the last one. I can reproduce the numbers of the question.

Comment: The way $A-B+C$ came about was finding the pattern in the definite integrals as n went from 1 to 11.  What got me stuck was the "recipe" - I like that description! - for $B$.

Comment: Not sure what you've done, but is it useful to take the summation in the integral? That is, consider $\int_0^1 \ln^2(x)\ln(1-x) \, dx \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2}$. Wolfram gives $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2} = Li_2(x)/x$, where $Li_2(x)$ is the polylogarithmic function and is known in QED. It appears to have some expansions in terms of log functions.

Comment: Thanks @jim !! That is exactly the trick that did it !! The answer is $-\frac{\pi^6}{2835}$ Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. I never knew you could do that !!!

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why this question has been [closed] as 'off topic'? I made a lot of changes to improve the clarity and formatting but it still went from [on hold] to [closed]. It generated good consideration and was answered. The result certainly helped me and was quite interesting. I feel it was "reworded to fit the rules in the help center" but none of the 5 who voted to close made a comment or contacted me. I don't get it ! Does it belong on another stack-exchange site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use [some MZVs algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function#Two_parameters_case).

For $n\geq1$, set
$$
 I_n:=\frac1{n^2}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)\:dx,
$$ then, differentiating the [Euler beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) three times, one gets
$$
I_n=-\frac4{n^6}-2\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^5}+2\frac{\frac{\pi^2}6-H_{n-1,2}}{n^4}+2\frac{\zeta(3)-H_{n-1,3}}{n^3}
$$ summing with respect to $n$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n=-4\zeta(6)-2\zeta(5,1)+\frac{\pi^2}3\zeta(4)-2\zeta(4,2)+2\zeta(3)^2-2\zeta(3,3),
$$ using
$$
\begin{align}
\zeta(5,1)&=-\frac12\zeta(3)^2 +\frac{\pi^6}{1260}
\\\\ \zeta(4,2)&= \zeta(3)^2 -\frac{4\pi^6}{2835}
\\\\ \zeta(3,3)&=\frac12\zeta(3)^2 -\frac{\pi^6}{1890}
\end{align}
$$ leads to

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^6}{2835}
> $$

or

> $$
> \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)}x=-\frac{\pi^6}{2835}.
> $$

Probably there is  a direct path using $\rm{Li}_2(\cdot)$ properties.

Comment: There is another solution to this exact same question on Brilliant.org by Aman Rajput which I do not understand but users here might. He turns the question into a double sum. Olivier Oloa - is this what you mean by "a direct path" ? https://brilliant.org/problems/possibly-the-hardest-calculus-problem/

Comment: @BobKadylo Sorry, but I can't see the suggested solution.

Comment: I will try to outline Aman Rajput's solution. First, he expresses  $ln(1-x)=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{m}$  then  $\displaystyle-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac {x^{m+n-1} \ln^2(x)}{mn^2}dx$  then  $\displaystyle-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(m+n)^3mn^2}$   leading up to $-2\times \frac {\zeta(6)}{6}$  and finally   $-\frac {\pi^6}{2835}$

Comment: @OlivierOloa, could you please elaborate a bit, for completeness, what you mean by differentiating the euler beta integral.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I am just learning MathJax. Aman did not show full details - but I hope there is enough here that you can make some sense of it. I did not realize you wouldn't see the stuff on Brilliant.org unless you were registered. Sorry. I just hope sharing this much helps some users on here.

Comment: @andre Sure. One has $\int_0^1 x^{s-1}\ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)\:dx=\left. \partial^2_s \partial_t \int_0^1 x^{s-1}(1-x)^{t-1}\:dx\right|_{s=n\, t=1}=\left. \partial^2_s \partial_t \frac{\Gamma(s)\,\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(s+t)}\right|_{s=n\, t=1}$ then polygamma terms appear which are reduced to harmonic numbers.

Comment: @OlivierOloa, really nice +1

Answer (score 1):

With @jim's help, I finally got it to be $\displaystyle -\frac{\pi^6}{2835}$ .I will try to figure out MathJax Details soon.

Of course, this means my $B=2\zeta(3)^2+\frac{23\pi^6}{5670}$

Comment: This reminds me of formula (40) from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html which states $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n,2}}{n^4} = (\zeta(3))^2 - \frac{\pi^6}{2835}$.

Comment: It should be possible to rewrite the series involving the $\psi$-functions from my answer below into such series with power harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Only an intermediate result, not a proof.

The following GNU Maxima 5.36.1 script results in zeros, so $D(n)$ should be tried for calculating the integrals.

```
D(n) :=
    -1/n*psi[2](n+1)
    +2/n^2*psi[1](n+1)
    -2/n^3*psi[0](n+1)
    -2/n^3*%gamma;

for n : 20 thru 50 do block(
    print(factor(integrate(x^(n-1)*log(x)*log(x)*log(1-x),x,0,1)-D(n)))
);
```